# How to fix Gmail that won't get new messages from IMAP server

Tags: gmail, imap

My wife has a cheap oangcc android tablet bought from Amazon.

She uses it to check her email on Google, and on a local Cyrus-
IMAP server.

It has worked fine for years, but now won't collect new mail from
the local imap server. It says it is synching, the whirly thing
comes up for a short time, but new mail doesn't arrive.

The local server has a self-signed certificate. The IMAP settings are port 143 and STARTTLS (accept all certificates).

If I use a different android device, it all works fine.

If I delete her email account on the tablet, and re-create it, it
gets all the email OK. But then, after a short while, new emails
aren't collected any more.

I even tried deleting the gmail data and cache, and recreating
the account. The problem still came back.

I have turned on logging for her mailbox on the cyrus server, and
it is having conversations with the server.

I can't see anywhere where it is asking to download mail from her
inbox.

The conversations from an attempt to sync from her tablet are:

```
>1691229516>5 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL 
RIGHTS=kxte QUOTA MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS 
NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE 
CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY 
THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE LIST-
EXTENDED WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-
NETSCAPE LOGINDISABLED AUTH=PLAIN COMPRESS=DEFLATE IDLE] User 
logged in SESSIONID=<router.moorsbroadband.net-11011-1691229516-
1>
<1691229516<6 CAPABILITY
>1691229516>* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL 
RIGHTS=kxte QUOTA MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS 
NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE 
CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY 
THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE LIST-
EXTENDED WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-
NETSCAPE LOGINDISABLED AUTH=PLAIN COMPRESS=DEFLATE IDLE
6 OK Completed
<1691229516<7 NAMESPACE
>1691229516>* NAMESPACE (("INBOX/" "/")) (("user/" "/")) (("" 
"/"))
7 OK Completed
<1691229516<8 STATUS "INBOX/Sent" (UIDVALIDITY)
>1691229516>* STATUS INBOX/Sent (UIDVALIDITY 1392197170)
8 OK Completed
<1691229516<9 NOOP
>1691229516>9 OK Completed
<1691229517<10 SELECT "INBOX/Sent"
>1691229517>* 1875 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Forwarded)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen 
$Forwarded \*)] Ok
* OK [UNSEEN 1] Ok
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1392197170] Ok
* OK [UIDNEXT 2030] Ok
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1741] Ok
* OK [URLMECH INTERNAL] Ok
10 OK [READ-WRITE] Completed
<1691229517<11 UID SEARCH HEADER MESSAGE-ID <4f8f645d-95e9-4a0f-
809e-f4b6be40ab78@email.android.com>
>1691229517>* SEARCH
11 OK Completed (0 msgs in 0.010 secs)
<1691229517<12 UID SEARCH (HEADER MESSAGE-ID <4f8f645d-95e9-
4a0f-809e-f4b6be40ab78@email.android.com>)
>1691229517>* SEARCH
12 OK Completed (0 msgs in 0.010 secs)
```

```
>1691229530>5 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL 
RIGHTS=kxte QUOTA MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS 
NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE 
CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY 
THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE LIST-
EXTENDED WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-
NETSCAPE LOGINDISABLED AUTH=PLAIN COMPRESS=DEFLATE IDLE] User 
logged in SESSIONID=<router.moorsbroadband.net-11132-1691229530-
1>
<1691229530<6 CAPABILITY
>1691229530>* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL 
RIGHTS=kxte QUOTA MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS 
NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE 
CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY 
THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE LIST-
EXTENDED WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-
NETSCAPE LOGINDISABLED AUTH=PLAIN COMPRESS=DEFLATE IDLE
6 OK Completed
<1691229530<7 NAMESPACE
>1691229530>* NAMESPACE (("INBOX/" "/")) (("user/" "/")) (("" 
"/"))
7 OK Completed
<1691229530<8 NOOP
>1691229530>8 OK Completed
<1691229530<9 LIST "" "INBOX/*"
>1691229530>* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX/Deleted Items"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX/Drafts
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX/SPAM
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX/Sent
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX/Sent Items"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX/Trash
9 OK Completed (0.000 secs 7 calls)
```

```
>1691229531>5 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL 
RIGHTS=kxte QUOTA MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS 
NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE 
CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY 
THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE LIST-
EXTENDED WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-
NETSCAPE LOGINDISABLED AUTH=PLAIN COMPRESS=DEFLATE IDLE] User 
logged in SESSIONID=<router.moorsbroadband.net-10992-1691229531-
1>
<1691229531<6 CAPABILITY
>1691229531>* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL 
RIGHTS=kxte QUOTA MAILBOX-REFERRALS NAMESPACE UIDPLUS 
NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE 
CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY 
THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE LIST-
EXTENDED WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-
NETSCAPE LOGINDISABLED AUTH=PLAIN COMPRESS=DEFLATE IDLE
6 OK Completed
<1691229531<7 NAMESPACE
>1691229531>* NAMESPACE (("INBOX/" "/")) (("user/" "/")) (("" 
"/"))
7 OK Completed
<1691229531<8 STATUS "INBOX/Sent" (UIDVALIDITY)
>1691229531>* STATUS INBOX/Sent (UIDVALIDITY 1392197170)
8 OK Completed
<1691229531<9 NOOP
>1691229531>9 OK Completed
<1691229531<10 SELECT "INBOX/Sent"
>1691229531>* 1875 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Forwarded)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen 
$Forwarded \*)] Ok
* OK [UNSEEN 1] Ok
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1392197170] Ok
* OK [UIDNEXT 2030] Ok
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1741] Ok
* OK [URLMECH INTERNAL] Ok
10 OK [READ-WRITE] Completed
<1691229531<11 UID SEARCH HEADER MESSAGE-ID <4f8f645d-95e9-4a0f-
809e-f4b6be40ab78@email.android.com>
>1691229531>* SEARCH
11 OK Completed (0 msgs in 0.010 secs)
<1691229531<12 UID SEARCH (HEADER MESSAGE-ID <4f8f645d-95e9-
4a0f-809e-f4b6be40ab78@email.android.com>)
>1691229531>* SEARCH
12 OK Completed (0 msgs in 0.010 secs)
```